# How to pass "#" as a valid parameter in feature file using java cucumber

Tags: java, cucumber, feature-file

I have to pass "#" symbol as parameter in feature file. How to achieve that as # symbol represents comments in feature file

Comment: # is used for comments normally. Did you try escaping the character maybe?

Comment: Yes but it did not work

Comment: The # is only a comment when used at the start of a line.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using cucumber version 4.x.x or above you can use **(.*)** regular expression in step definition to take any kind of parameters.

Sample Feature File:

```
Scenario: User searches for a character in Search
When The user searches for # in the Search
```

Sample Step Definition:

```
@When("The user searches for (.*) in the Search")
```